# ManagedExecutorService not found

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, executorservice, jboss-arquillian

I have a problem with Arquillian and `ManagedExecutorService`s. Arquillian is not able to find the default `ManagedExecutorService`. The Exception is:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No object bound to name java:comp/DefaultManagedExecutorService
```

I am using IntelliJ and execute the test with `GlassFish Embedded 3.1` with Arquillian `1.4.0.Final`.

Here is my Unit Test:

```
@Slf4j
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class WorkhorseTest {

    @Inject
    private Workhorse workhorse;

    @Deployment
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
                .addClass(Workhorse.class)
                .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
    }

    @Test
    public void testExecution() throws Exception {
        final Future<Integer> result = workhorse.execute();
        result.get(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        log.info("Executed...");
    }
}
```

Here is the EJB:

```
@Slf4j
@Singleton
public class Workhorse {

    @Resource
    private ManagedExecutorService mes;

    public Future<Integer> execute() {
        return mes.submit(() -> {
            log.info("Hello from a Runnable");
            return 5;
        });
    }


}
```

How can I test `ManagedExecutorService`s with Arquillian?

Comment: Might be because the default managedexecutor that ships with JBoss is named differently, so you'll need to specifically supply a JNDI name in your `@Resource` annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with switching a dependency in `pom.xml`:

Old:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

New:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
    <version>5.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```